# php if no image make bootstrap colulmn col-md-12

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, joomla, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is my first post, but I have used this site a lot in the past. I am a php novice, but i am goof with bootstrap, html, css and Joomla.

I am using K2 in Joomla, and i need to change the K2 category item layout (example here: www.caravanningoz.com.au/news )

At the moment I have the image set to the left with a bootstrap 3 col-md-5 AND then the intro text to the right of the image is set with a col-md-7.

The problem I have (i am sure many can tell already) is that IF there is no image uploaded, then there is a big white space on the left where the image should be.

I want to be able to use some php code to say "if there is no image, then set remove the image col-md-5 and make the introtext col-md-12 (so it fits across the entire column).

here is most of the code from the k2 category item layout php file:

```
<div class="row">

<div class="catItemView group<?php echo ucfirst($this->item->itemGroup); ?><?php echo ($this->item->featured) ? ' catItemIsFeatured' : ''; ?><?php if($this->item->params->get('pageclass_sfx')) echo ' '.$this->item->params->get('pageclass_sfx'); ?>">
<div class="catItemImage left col-md-5 col-sm-5">

  <?php if($this->item->params->get('catItemImage') && !empty($this->item->image)): ?>
  <!-- Item Image -->

<a class="categoryItemImage" href="<?php echo $this->item->link; ?>" title="<?php if(!empty($this->item->image_caption)) echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($this->item->image_caption); else echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($this->item->title); ?>">
<div class=" grow-up drop-shadow">
<img class="img-responsive caption" src="<?php echo $this->item->image; ?>" alt="<?php if(!empty($this->item->image_caption)) echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($this->item->image_caption); else echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($this->item->title); ?>" style="width:<?php echo $this->item->imageWidth; ?>px; height:auto;" />
            </div>
        </a>

  <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<div class="catItemContent right col-md-7 col-sm-7">
    <!-- Plugins: BeforeDisplay -->
<?php echo $this->item->event->BeforeDisplay; ?>

<!-- K2 Plugins: K2BeforeDisplay -->
<?php echo $this->item->event->K2BeforeDisplay; ?>
```

```
  <?php if($this->item->params->get('catItemTitle')): ?>
  <!-- Item title -->
  <h3 class="catItemTitle">
        <?php if(isset($this->item->editLink)): ?>
        <!-- Item edit link -->
        <span class="catItemEditLink">
<a class="modal" rel="{handler:'iframe',size:{x:990,y:550}}" href="<?php echo $this->item->editLink; ?>">
                <?php echo JText::_('K2_EDIT_ITEM'); ?>
            </a>
        </span>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($this->item->params->get('catItemTitleLinked')): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->item->link; ?>">
        <?php echo $this->item->title; ?>
    </a>
    <?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $this->item->title; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if($this->item->params->get('catItemFeaturedNotice') && $this->item->featured): ?>
    <!-- Featured flag -->
    <span>
        <sup>
            <?php echo JText::_('K2_FEATURED'); ?>
        </sup>
    </span>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </h3>
  <?php endif; ?>



    <?php if($this->item->params->get('catItemAuthor')): ?>
    <!-- Item Author -->
    <span class="catItemAuthor">
        <?php echo K2HelperUtilities::writtenBy($this->item->author->profile->gender); ?> 
        <?php if(isset($this->item->author->link) && $this->item->author->link): ?>
<a rel="author" href="<?php echo $this->item->author->link; ?>"><?php echo $this->item->author->name; ?></a>
        <?php else: ?>
        <?php echo $this->item->author->name; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </span>
    <?php endif; ?>

<div class="clr"></div>

<div>

            <?php if($this->item->params->get('catItemDateCreated')): ?>
    <!-- Date created -->
    <span class="catItemDateCreated">
        <?php echo JHTML::_('date', $this->item->created , JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC3')); ?>
    </span>
    <?php endif; ?>


     <?php if($this->item->params->get('catItemCategory')): ?>
            <!-- Item category name -->
            <span class="catItemCategory">
                <span><?php echo JText::_('K2_PUBLISHED_IN'); ?></span>
<a href="<?php echo $this->item->category->link; ?>"><?php echo $this->item->category->name; ?></a>
            </span>
            <?php endif; ?>


    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this at the top of the script you posted:

```
<?php
    if(!empty($this->item->image)) {
        $class = "col-md-5 col-sm-5";
    } else {
        $class = "col-md-12 col-sm-12";
    }
?>
```

Now you can use `$class` in place of "col-md-7 col-sm-7".

Answer (score 1):

There is already an `if` statement to check if the image exists, so all you need to do it put your container div inside, like so:

```
<?php if($this->item->params->get('catItemImage') && !empty($this->item->image)) { ?>
    <!-- Item Image -->
    <div class="catItemImage left col-md-5 col-sm-5">
        <a class="categoryItemImage" href="<?php echo $this->item->link; ?>" title="<?php if(!empty($this->item->image_caption)) echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($this->item->image_caption); else echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($this->item->title); ?>">
            <div class=" grow-up drop-shadow">
                <img class="img-responsive caption" src="<?php echo $this->item->image; ?>" alt="<?php if(!empty($this->item->image_caption)) echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($this->item->image_caption); else echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($this->item->title); ?>" style="width:<?php echo $this->item->imageWidth; ?>px; height:auto;" />
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="catItemContent right col-md-7 col-sm-7">
<?php } else { ?>
    <div class="catItemContent right col-md-12">
<?php } ?>
```